# How to close browser (driver.quit / driver.close) and launch browser again in same test case in cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I have to code scenario where with below cucumber steps

```
Scenario: Relaunched close browser
Given user launches the application
When user logs in with credentials 
And user verifies logout button
And user closes the browser
And user opens browser and launches again
Then user should be taken to login page
```

we have `@before` hook written which initializes the browser and launch the application
but when I am closing the browser in middle of the test case then driver is lost. Now is there anyway I can call the `@before` hook post closing the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

try using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where driver management done by QAF. You don't need to create driver. If you want to quite just do teardown it will automatically create new driver session when next time requested. Further more when you change `driver.name` property in code it will tear down current driver and create new requested driver.